# search a word inside file then stored in array

Tags: java, arrays, readfile

my problem is i read a file then i search a word "(:types"
i want take the words after "(:types" but the code take a line after "(:types" 
this is the problem i need to you to find why my code cant store words after
 "(:types" ( my code take "
           location vehicle cargo)" i need to take ( "space fuel
           location vehicle cargo")

sorry for my English

> (:types space fuel
>
> ```
>    location vehicle cargo)
> ```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.List;

import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.compiler.sym;


public class type2 {


public static void main(String[] args){


    String filePath = "C:\\test4.txt";

    BufferedReader br;

    String line = "";

    String read=null;

    List<String> temps = new LinkedList<String>();


    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        try {
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {


                String[] words = line.split(" ");

                for (String word : words) {
                  if (word.equals("(:types") ) {
                      while((read = br.readLine()) != null){
                          temps.add(read);
                          if (word.equals("(:predicates") );
                              break;

                         }
                        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);
                          String [] type=tempsArray[0].split(" ");

                          System.out.println(tempsArray[0]);

                  }

                }
            }

            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you aren't getting the words that are on the same line is because you don't parse the rest of the line.

First you get the first line with

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

And then split that on all the spaces with:

```
String[] words = line.split(" ");
```

But once you find the string `(:types`, all you do is start reading from the file again. You never parse the remaining parts of the array `words`.

If you want to parse the rest of this array, maybe find the index of the string `(:types` in your array, then just parse all parts after it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem very straightforward.

If I understand you correctly you have a file which contain the lines:

```
(:types space fuel 
location vehicle cargo)
```

You want to find the line containing "(:types" and then save "space" and "fuel".

In your code your read in a new line of text like this

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

You check line for whether it contains (:types and if it does you store the words in the *next* line through the code:

```
while((read = br.readLine()) != null){
    temps.add(read);
```

This above is your problem. To fix this you should change the above code to the following:

```
for (String word : words){
    if(!word.equals("(:types")){
        temps.add(read);
    }
}
```